# Running R code via Rstudio on a remote server not by browser

Tags: r, rstudio, hpc, slurm, rstudio-server

Is there a way to use a local Rstudio installation on my machine which is actually running the code on a remote server where I can run distributed jobs via SLURM?
Can it be compatible with version control and dockers?

Comment: Of course but that has little to do with RStudio -- set up slurm as you need to (including ssh keys) and just the jobs _from the command-line_ as one does with these tools.

Comment: I'm planning to use rslurm package which runs the slurm commands directly from R, sos I need my Rstudio to run it's code directly on the server. Is what you are saying compatible with this?

Comment: You can use rslurm to create the script needed for submission (see the vignette section where `submit` is set to `FALSE`) locally within RStudio and then move the folder (better yet - use version control to pull it) to a SLURM head node and submit the job on the command line. Or you can use rslurm on the server head node and actually submit the job even without RStudio by just running R from the command line.

Comment: why not via browser? would a remote desktop do the job?

Comment: You can use RStudio on the remote machine. It is not the best (a bit slow, from my own experience), but if you want to try it, you can checkout these instructions [here](https://github.com/USCbiostats/software-dev/wiki/Running-RStudio-on-the-HPC).

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

The `remoter` package does what you are wanting to do very well. You start R on the remote server and run `remoter :: server(showmsg=TRUE)`. Then in you local RStudio you run
`remoter :: client ()`. Works fairly flawlessly.

My main issue is that when you run help it comes from the remote session in the console rather than the help window.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/remoter/vignettes/remoter.pdf